# SQL (MariaDB) SUM times limitation

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have query where I SUM times by group

```
SELECT category,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ter_ura_zakljucek, ter_ura_zacetek)))) AS total_time
GROUP_BY 'category'
```

This seems to work fine on smaller amount of data, but when I execute it on larger amount of rows it seems it always stops at total_time = 838:59:59

Is there some limitation in SQL at amount of times you can sum up?

Comment: No `FROM` clause needed?

Comment: Sorry, SQL is from Laravel query and I forgot to include FROM part of it to my question. It is included in my original Laravel query :)

Comment: @Kamuffel, no need to delete your answer. (I just wanted to clarify the difference between standard SQL and the MariaDB behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range for TIME-datatype is '-838:59:59.999999' to '838:59:59.999999'. See the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time/).

To handle larger time values you have to covert it to something else depending on your need.

Comment: Thank you @slaakso. I guess I should read official docs more carefully next time (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time/) :)

I managed to get around this limint by just doing SUM of seconds with

'SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ter_ura_zakljucek, ter_ura_zacetek))) AS seconds'

and then doing conversion to HH:mm format in PHP.